# Changing the value of a column in an entry using $wpdb

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a table in my WordPress application, with some entries present. One of the columns in my table is `flag`, which could either be `1` or `0` depending on a condition. BY default, all entries have the `flag` column set as `1`.

Now, I'm trying to change the value of `flag` for some entries from `1` to `0` as follows:

```
$res = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_q33uds_campaign WHERE flag = 1 ORDER BY date1' );
foreach($res as $re)
{
    $re->flag = 0;
}
```

However, the above method doesn't seem to change the value of the `flag` column from `1` to `0`. Am I trying to do this the wrong way?

Comment: You can't change the value of a variable in php and expect the value in database to magically update. Use an UPDATE query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can use update query to change flag value

```
$wpdb->update(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        $wpdb->prefix.'item_info', // table name
        array(
            'post_id'       => $post_id, // table column that need change
            'item_stock'    => $item_stock
        ),
        array('post_id' => $post_id) // id of table
    )
);
```

Comment: How would this query change if none of my rows in the table have any unique id associated with it?

Comment: i mention already you change id on some id base here i use post id you can use you table unique id eg you want change flag 1 to 0 where primary id is 13 ust simple post id 13 chagne value

Comment: My table doesn't have a primary key or unique column. How would the query work in that case?

Comment: then on which you are enter data value in table. how we drink water without glass